# Play command and its output

Tags: command-line

I have problem with `play` command and its huge output. I wanted to disable output from this command by added `>/dev/null` but it still produces the same huge output. What can I do to fix it? Full command is for example `play whatever.mp3 >/dev/null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's presumably because the outputs you are still getting are being sent on the STDERR (file descriptor 2) stream, not on the STDOUT (file descriptor 1) stream.

Normally, warning and error messages are sent on the STDERR, and regular output on STDOUT stream.

If you want to disable outputting on STDERR too, send the file descriptor 2 to `/dev/null` too:

```
play >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or in `bash` (or `zsh`, `ksh`):

```
play &>/dev/null
```